# Why does Ubuntu Software Center not store the Universe source?

Tags: software-center, source

I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS with LXDE on a msi notebook.
 Whenever I go to install something from Ubuntu Software Center which is from the 'Universe' source I always have to click 'use this source' and wait for it to load it. I am able to install whatever it was I wanted and exit USC fine but the next time I go to install something from that source I have to go through all that again. What am I doing wrong and why isn't it storing the 'Universe' source?

Comment: Why isn't Universe selected now when it is by default is a much intriguing question. Perhaps you should open Settings > Software Properties and tick Universe?

Comment: Not sure where Settings > Software Properties is but is but when I go to Software and Updates in Ubuntu Software Center, Universe is ticked there.